# batch rename folders with value from json value in package.json

Tags: grep, terminal, regular-expression, rename, batch-jobs

This is a bit of a crazy one, but I am wondering if it is even possible.

I have maybe 300 folders in my `/var/www` folder that were all renamed to the same name `[Name](Num)` so `kindred (19)` for example.

Almost every single one of these folders has a file called `package.json` which all have a `name` key value pair which then has the name of the project in side that.

```
{
  "name": "a useful project name",
   ......
  "main": "src/index.js",
}
```

I would like the folder that contains the `package.json` to be renamed to whatever the value of "name" is inside the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the better tools to use when you need to parse json files is [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). That makes it easy to extract the `name` field from the `package.json` file in a directory. Performing the rename is a simple bit of shell scripting:

```
$ cd /var/www
$ for d in */; do  # *1
>    if [ -f "${d}package.json" ]; then  # *2
>        new_name=$(jq -e -M -r .name "${d}package.json")  # *3
>        if [ $? -eq 0 ] && ! [ -e "${new_name}" ]; then  # *4
>            mv "${d}" "${new_name}"  # *5
>        fi
>    fi
> done
```

Some notes:

*1: `*/` expands to all the directories in the current directory. Each directory name will include a `/` on the end, so we do not put one in later at *2 and *3.

*2: Only process directories that have a `package.json` file.

*3: Invoke `jq` to extract the name field from `package.json`. We invoke `jq` with `-r` to output raw strings (i.e. leave off the double quotes), with `-M` to not have colored output, and `-e` to have `jq` exit with an error if there is no `name` field.

*4: Check that `jq` ran successfully (there was a `name` field) and that the new name for the directory does not already exist. You may want to split these up and add an `else` if you want to output an error message for the two cases where you're skipping the rename.

*5: Rename the directory.

For a test run, I'd put `echo` in front of the `mv` command at *5 and check the output to see that the renaming looks right. I haven't tested this myself as I don't have a bunch of directories with `package.json` files.

Comment: I changed ` $? -ne 0` to ` $? -ne 1` and it worked a treat :D

Comment: @JamieHutber Yeah, sorry. Stupid typo. I've changed it from `-ne` to `-eq` which is better than checking `-ne 1` as `jq` could return a different error code.